# How do I implement a UINavigationController in this case?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

**current version of my project :**

> I have 5 different `UIViewControllers` in my app. I've set my
>   `FirstViewController` to be the `Initial View Controller` using the
>   Attributes Inspector. I move back and forth from one ViewController to
>   another by using buttons to which I assign modal segues, from one
>   ViewController to another, using the StoryBoard

**What I want to change:**

> I want to keep the navigation buttons obviously, delete the modal segues and use
>   a `UINavigationController` instead. If I understand the concept
>   correctly, when using a `UINavigationController` I need to go into each
>   `UIButton-IBAction` and at the very end of the method I have to push the next
>   ViewController I want to move to, onto my NavigationController (do I also
>   have to pop the current one first?). However, I can't figure out how
>   to implement all that correctly.

**What I've done so far:**

- I removed all modal segues from the storyboard and kept the navigation buttons along with their corresponding IBActions
- I unchecked the box in the Attributes Inspector that was making my FirstViewController the initial View Controller of my app
- I went into my **AppDelegate.m** and tried to create the Navigation Controller there and make my FirstViewController be the RootViewController

**MyAppDelegate.m**

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIViewController *myFirstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *myNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myFirstViewController];

    [myNavigationController pushViewController:myFirstViewController animated:YES];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    return YES;
}
```

- I then tried to test if the above was working by going into the IBAction of a
  navigation button on my FirstViewController and implemented the
  following in order to move to my SecondViewController when the
  button is pressed :

**FirstViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)goRightButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    // some code drawing the ButtonIsPressed UIImageView on the current View Controller

    UIViewController *mySecondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mySecondViewController animated:YES];
}
```

but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: One upvote just for the clarity of your question.

Answer (score 2):

You are not linking your XIB file. Please add your navigation controller as

```
UIViewController *myFirstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myFirstViewController];
```

Use following code to move from one view to another

```
UIViewController *mySecondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mySecondViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Did you use `navigationController = ..` directly instead of `UINavigationController *navigationController = ` on purpose or by mistake?

Comment: this only works if you are not loading the views interface from a storyboard, but from an individual xib file

Comment: UINavigationController *navigationController is required for sure, but I declared navigation controller in AppDelegate.h, so i did not write it in this code

Comment: got a bit confused with Eric's suggestion that seems to "cancel" yours. Will try both and come back and choose the answer that fits my case :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a storyboard, you should just drag in the navigation controller there and hook it up to your app delegates.  As long as it is the main storyboard, and you have identified a view controller to load first, you do not need to load any views in your app delegate.

In order to push a view programmatically that's in a storyboard, you need to do something like the following:

```
 //bundle can be nil if in main bundle, which is default
 UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
 MyCustomViewController *customVC = (MyCustomViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"customVC"];
//standard way
[self.navigationController pushViewController:customVC animated:YES];

//custom animation
[UIView transitionWithView:self.navigationController.view duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp animations:^{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:customVC animated:NO];
} completion:nil];
```

You identify the view controller with the identifier you add in the storyboard editor.  Below are some screenshots to help show what I mean.

[image: navigation controller with arrow to indicate initial load]

[image: place where you change the identifier of the view controller, so you can call it]